# Building an Instapaper clone

Tags: c#, html, text, data-mining

I'm currently building a Instapaper clone and need some help designing the algorithm.

It has two components:

1. Extract the main text block from an HTML document
2. If the save article has more than 1 page then extract text from all pages

Can you guys point me to the right direction?
I will be using .NET 4 C# for this project.

Comment: This is kind of like saying "I'd like to build a compiler.  It has two componets, thing that reads the code, and the code generator.  Can you guys point me in the right direction"?

Comment: Not asking you to do it for me. Just want some recommendations.

Comment: What do you mean by question #2?  Typically html don't have the concept of multiple pages unless they are being printed or the developer built in method of providing chunks of the full document.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to extract the stuff you need from the HTML document.
2. Same as #1.

I suppose that doesn't provide you with much direction, but you didn't provide me with much direction, either.

Comment: How can you detect if the article is on multiple page?

Comment: @Jason: I don't understand that question.  Do you mean how can you detect if an article has multiple pages (e.g. [Hidden Features of .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c) has 11 pages of answers)? The easiest way is to search for urls with names or alt text like numbers or the word "next", as well as to search for `rel="next"` in the `a` tags.  Though this is something to be careful about, since some urls might be made up of 100s of pages (e.g., blogs or webcomics).